# File_get_html return empty html in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, user-agent, simple-html-dom

I made a script that was getting content from another site using Simple HTML DOM Parser. It looked like this

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://csgolounge.com/'.$tradeid);       

foreach($html->find('div[id=tradediv]') as $trade) {
    $when = $trade->find('.tradeheader')[0];
 }
```

I was probably looking for content too often (every 30 secs) , and now i get empty html back.

I tryed to change User agent like this

```
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params($context, array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6\r\n'));
$html = file_get_html('http://csgolounge.com/profile?id='.$steamid, 0, $context);
```

But am still getting back empty html.

Comment: You have probably gotten your script blocked by attentive admins at this remote site

Comment: @Jeff What can i do about it ?

Comment: Many  websites have policies that declare you are not allowed to scrape their data. Perhaps you need to contact them about a partnership agreement?

Comment: Hm , I am pretty sure many people scrape their data , i just have to find a way. Now I have fetch html using cURL. Can i somehow save it and than process it using Simple HTML DOM Parser ?

Comment: Sure, just use str_get_html on the response

Comment: Actualy i think i found out what was the problem. Simple_html_dom.php has define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000) and it looks like my html was just a bit over it. So i changed it to 900000 and now its working. I was never blocked. Thanks for help anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that my html file was too big . Simple html dom has defined max file size define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000). I changed it to 900000 and now its working again.

Comment: after messing with many things on google ended up with this answer 
great...saved a lot of time